# In Coldufsion, is it better to return query data in a struct or the query?

Tags: coldfusion, struct

Simple question today: Is it better to return query data in a struct or return the query itself? This is in context of displaying the information in a readable format. (Typical data system.) I have done it by query till now, however I was thinking about making a async. sorting function (like an arrow on the top of a column). Would it better to put the query into a struct and then have sorting functions on the struct...or would it just be better to re-query the information? I'm thinking it would be better to do the struct, especially with large data...comments?

Is there a way to sort queries as they come?

Note: I don't want to use CFGrid...for learning purposes and other reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ColdFusion returns a dataset that you can reference directly, I see no reason to waste time dumping it into a struct.

If you don't want to run the query a 2nd time, you can always run a query of queries and just resort the data that way.

Comment: actually, just as you posted this I read that you can use a sort function on the query by column! I'll probably use either method depending on what I need! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Returning the query would make the function more reusable.  If you need it in a particular format, write a function that returns the data in that particular format, but internally that method would call the original function to get the query data.

```
public query function getData() {
    ...
    return myQuery;
}

public struct function getDataForGrid() {
    var data = getData();
    ...
    return myStruct;
}
```

On the 2nd method you could also do a returntype of "any" and return whatever datatype you need.

The first method could also be declared private if you don't ever intend to access the query data directly.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a query object is basically a struct of array's already  :

```
queryName.fieldName[rowNumber]
```